# What is the structure of a video stream?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

The end goal is to process the RGB data of a video.

I am trying to read the bytes of a file that I have created using ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -video_size 100x100 -framerate 20 -f x11grab -i :0.0 \
    -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -video.nut
```

I wrote a [node script](https://gist.github.com/mjpuser/c230b55f981527e1f837105fccc7686b) to help make it easier to read the binary data if you need it.  The output of my current file is:

```
Hex Binary   Row
47  01000111 0
40  01000000 1
11  00010001 2
10  00010000 3
03  00000011 4
00  00000000 5
00  00000000 6
00  00000000 7
68  01101000 8
```

I see [the spec for a .nut](http://ffmpeg.org/~michael/nut.txt), but I can't figure it out.  I would like to be able to parse out the RGB data for each frame so that I am left with a RGB matrix for each "image" in the video stream.  Thanks!

Comment: run ffprobe on video.raw and post the output

Comment: @szatmary ffprobe is returning an error (https://gist.github.com/mjpuser/edb891d0af2680e657249cf6fd96f7ee).  I compiled ffmpeg according to https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Comment: Looks like ffmpeg does not support muxing raw video into TS. ffplay won't play it.

Comment: How do you know the issue is with ffmpeg and rawvideo, and not ffplay?

Comment: Updated the question to use .nut instead of mpegts.

Comment: If ffmpeg encodes and muxes it in spec, ffplay will play it. They use the same libraries underneath. What's your end goal - how will you work with the file generated?

Comment: I'd like to process the RGB data.

Comment: So, can you accept rawvideo stream?

Comment: @Mulvya I'm a ffmpeg newb, so I'm not sure what you mean.  I'd just like to parse out RGB data.  Whatever format is easiest to do that in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're ok with parsing raw video then use

```
ffmpeg -video_size 100x100 -framerate 20 -f x11grab -i :0.0
       -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -f rawvideo video.rgb
```

The structure of the output will be

```
R G B R G B R G B ...
```

So each three byte triplet represents a pixel in scan order Left to Right, Top to Bottom. So, for a `100x100` frame, the 301st byte is the R value for the first pixel of the 2nd row. The 30000th byte is the B value for the pixel at the bottom-right corner. Then the next 30K bytes represent the next frame and so on.

This is a **raw** video stream, so no container metadata or frame encapsulation present. Just an undifferentiated stream of pixel channel values.

Comment: Thanks @Mulvya.  Can you point me to some place in the docs where it says that rawvideo is structured like this?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I like @Mulvya's answer. The **.rgb** format is much easier. However if you ever pass that file around, you will have to **always** include notes with it (such as : expected width, height, framerate etc), otherwise it's a sea of bytes with no idea where to stop per frame.

As for the **.nut** format as you previously asked...

Each video frame will be classed as a keyframe (since it's an uncompressed full image).

- First find the data section for your keyframes... Look for a start code sequence like this : 
   
  `4E 4B E4 AD EE CA 45 69`.
- To be sure this is the keyframes data section, the next following **8** bytes are always set as : 
   
  `06 00 00 00 00 00 00 03`.
- Then the next following bytes contain Flags and total bytes used for this keyframe (ie: **30000** for a `100 x 100 x 3` image). It gets tricky cos now you have to check at bit-level not just at byte-level... The short version of this story is (for a `100 x 100` image) is to just skip the next 4 bytes which should be `00 81 EA 30` to get to the 30 000 bytes of RGB data. 
  et as :

  (a) First frame skip 4 bytes (should be `00 81 EA 30`) + extract the following 30 000 bytes.

  (b) This leads to another keyframe code: `4E 4B E4 AD EE CA 45 69`. Followed by 15 skip-able bytes (of which the last one is `30`) and you get the 30K of image's RGB data.

  (c) For all other frames repeat step (b), whereby you : Skip **8** bytes of start code + Skip next following **15** bytes + Extract next **30 000** bytes for image. Repeat until end.

  - PS: As a final note... Those 4 bytes are only 4 because of total bits required for defining (flags etc) a 100 x 100 image. More bits will be used for a larger size image. In such a case, you really to parse the individual bits, also the final bits before a frame's data always give the size of bytes required for image extraction. Let me know if you need that info.

**OLD ANSWER**

> I can't figure out what format the payload is in. I checked wikipedia
>   for uncompressed video format, but that was no help...

`-f mpegts` means **force** the output format to be **mpegts** regardless of file extension. 
So you really have MPEG TS format and it's never been RAW format. 
Those 3 letters, r-a-w, in your filename are misleading.

I can't be sure what format you actually need when you only say *"uncompressed video"*. Is it RGB that you want? I only know of AVI and FLV as formats that support RGB frames (likely MOV can do it also but never tried it). In anycase you need a **container** for your RGB frame data

**AVI** container :

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 30 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 video.avi
```

**FLV** container :

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 30 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -c:v flashsv -pix_fmt rgb24 video.flv
```

**PS** : 
Maybe the info in **[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/347434)** can help you decide on your output format & container.

Comment: I updated my question to make it more clear.  I also changed the file name since that might be confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your input.